# Delete Mutiple SCCM Devices from SCCM

Tags: powershell

I used this command but I don't know how to suppress the confirmation message and force it to yes

```
Get-Content "C:\TEMP\ComputersToDelete.txt" | foreach { Remove-CMDevice -DeviceName $_ }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
Get-Help Remove-CMDevice -Online
```

You'll get to [this microsoft docs site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configurationmanager/remove-cmdevice?view=sccm-ps) where everything about this command is explained

You'll see that adding `-Force` will force the command to run without asking for user confirmation.

```
Get-Content "C:\TEMP\ComputersToDelete.txt" | foreach { Remove-CMDevice -DeviceName $_ -Force }
```

Btw. many cmdlets have a `-Force` parameter. it's most of the time for this exact purpose, suppressing the confirmation message.

Comment: I tried -Force inside and outside the brace no results

Comment: @sofiane like so? `Get-Content "C:\TEMP\ComputersToDelete.txt" | foreach { Remove-CMDevice -DeviceName $_ -Force }`